# How to register custom Querydsl EntityPathResolver with Spring Data MongoRepositoryFactory?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I am using the [Querydsl extension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl) (`QueryDslPredicateExecutor`) to my `CrudRepository`.

To reliably exclude the generated `Q` classes from my test coverage measurements, they are generated into a dedicated `querydsl` subpackage of the respective domain classes (annotation processor option `-Aquerydsl.packageSuffix=.querydsl`).

Alas, this causes a `ClassNotFoundException` at application start up:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Did not find a query class org.example.QDomain for domain class org.example.Domain!
        at org.springframework.data.querydsl.SimpleEntityPathResolver.createPath(SimpleEntityPathResolver.java:63)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QueryDslMongoRepository.<init>(QueryDslMongoRepository.java:85)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QueryDslMongoRepository.<init>(QueryDslMongoRepository.java:67)
    …
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.QDomain
    …
```

I have already located the [`EntityPathResolver` interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/EntityPathResolver.html) that supposedly would allow me to plug in my own *domain class* to *`Q` class* mapping that inserts the `.querydsl` package suffix, but I haven’t found a way to configure Spring Data’s `MongoRepositoryFactory` to pick my own `EntityPathResolver`.

Is this possible?

Comment: hi, have u found the solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only way is to create your own variant of the `MongoRepositoryFactory` because the instance of the `EntityPathResolver` is hard-wired into it.

Comment: I tried to do that, overriding {MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository}}, but {{getEntityInformation}} being private and hence not re-usable from my copy of {{getTargetRepository}} dissuaded be from that. Too much copy and paste for my taste – in particular, as my {{CustomEntityPathResolver}} would be almost identical to the non-extensible {{SimpleEntityPathResolver}} as well.